# Choosing a clever "test function" in Sobolev spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

> Given $\mathbf{f}$ with $f_1,...,f_N\in L^2(\Omega)$
>   $$\int_\Omega \mathbf{f} \cdot \nabla v = 0 \quad\forall v \in
>  H_0^1(\Omega)$$ we have $\mathbf{f} = \mathbf{0}$ a.e. since
>   $\mathbf{f} \in H^{-1}(\Omega)$.

Without using functional analysis, can we explicitly show the above result by cleverly choosing the test function?

> For example for $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ and $\int fg = 0 \;\;\forall g\in
>  L^2$, then choosing $g= f$, we have $$\int f^2 = 0 \quad \Rightarrow
>  \quad f=0 \text{ a.e. }$$

But here $\mathbf{f}$ might not be the weak gradient of a function.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your "result" is not true. Take $\Omega = (0,1)$ for simplicity. Then,
$$\int_0^1 f \, v' \, \mathrm{d} x = 0\quad\forall v \in H_0^1(\Omega)$$
just implies that $f$ is constant.

Comment: when you look at $\mathbf{f} \in H^{-1}$, you have that $$\|\mathbf{f}\|_{H^{-1}} = \max_i \{\|f_i\|_{L^2} \},$$ since $\|\mathbf{f}\|_{H^{-1}} = 0$, it forces $\mathbf{f} = \mathbf{0}$ a.e. It wasn't clear in my post, and I will edit it.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.